# Disabling contextmenu (the options seen on a right click) by adding event listener doesn't work

Tags: javascript

### Disabling `contextmenu` via an event handler

I am trying to disable right click on an element. I found a solution which does it like so:

```
<div oncontextmenu='return false'></div>
```

But since it is not a good practice to have event handlers in html, I tried something like:

```
<div id='test'></div>
```

and on the js part of the code:

```
let test = document.getElementById('test')

test.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
  console.log('right click!')
  return false
})
```

```js
let test2 = document.getElementById('test2')

test2.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
  console.log('right click!')
  return false
})
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#test1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#test2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='test1' oncontextmenu='return false'></div>
<div id='test2'></div>
```

Right click on `test1` would be successfully disabled, but not on `test2` and the console proves that the program control did reach the handler.

---

I am not looking for a workaround as

```
<div id='test'></div>

let test = document.getElementById('test')

test.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('right click!')
})
```

works perfectly.

---

I want to know, why are the two elements in the above snippet behaving differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is weird behaviour. For some reason, a `return false` from an `.addEventListener` does not work (tested in latest stable chrome). You need to call the `.preventDefault()` method as shown below *and* return `false` to get what you want in modern and ancient browsers. A right click is logged to the console but no context menu shows up.

Note that I added some semicolons for style. Although in your example they were not technically needed, it is a good practice to include them.

```js
let test2 = document.getElementById('test2')

test2.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
  console.log('right click!');
  e.preventDefault();//===added this===
  return false;
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#test1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#test2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='test1' oncontextmenu='return false'></div>
<div id='test2'></div>
```